# How to check given value present in nested array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am very new to the PHP, i want to check the value is present inside the associative array,please help me to acheive this thing.

```
public $array=[
  'id','name',
  'value.details'=>['type'=>'myFunction']
];
foreach($array as $key=>$condition){
if(in_array('myFunction',$array)){
//My logic
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know the keys:
`if($array['value.details']['type'] === 'myFunction') { }`

if you walk through your array:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
    if(is_array($val) && in_array('myFunction', $val)) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the $key and $val when `value.details` time

Comment: [value.details] => Array([type] => myFunction)

Answer (score 1):

Your array is mix of string and array, you might also wanna check the array inside your array.

```
$array=[
  'id','name',
  'value.details'=>['type'=>'myFunction']
];

$query = 'myFunction';    
$isPresent = false;

foreach ($array as $data) {
    if (gettype($data) === "array") {
        foreach ($data as $val) {
            if ($val === $query) {
                $isPresent = true;
                continue;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($query === $data) {
           $isPresent = true;
           continue;
        }
    }
}
```